# Forward a request coming to my CDN to another server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge, content-delivery-network

I'm trying to play Instagram Video assets. The challenge is the videos are expirable. They expire every N mins.

I'm brainstorming a solution where I set up my CDN (Cloudfront/Cloudflare) which forwards the incoming requests to the original server (Instagram in this case), caches the video at CDN, and then keeps serving it without the need to request Instagram again. I don't want to download the videos and keep them in my bucket. Is it even possible?

**====Update**

After @Ross Suggestion, I'd a look at CloudFront functions and was able to redirect the incoming requests to another URL, basis on some condition. Following is the code.

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var headers = request.headers;
    
    if request.uri == '/assets/1.jpg'{
        var newurl = 'https://instagram.com/media/1.jpg'
      
        var response = {
            statusCode: 302,
            statusDescription: 'Found',
            headers:
                { "location": { "value": newurl } }
        }

        return response;
     }
   return request
}
```

However, this redirects it to the newURL. What I'm looking for is not redirect, but the following

1. when the request is made to my server cdn, ie `mydomain.com/assets/1.jpg`, the file `1.jpg` should be served from the **instagram** server, whose value is the `newURL` in the above code snippet. This should be done without changing my domain URL (in the address bar) to instagram.
2. The following requests to `mydomain.com/assets/1.jpg` should be directly served from the cache, and should not be routed again to instagram.

Comment: The best way to accomplish this is to build your own bespoke solution that runs at the edge. You can use Cloudflare Workers to accomplish this: https://workers.cloudflare.com/ Cloudfront functions should have the same functionality: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/ . You should also be able to store files and alter cache with these products. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Haven;t tried anything yet! I was unsure whether such a possibility even exist or not. I'll give it a quick read, and will reach out if required. Thanks @RossJacobs.

Comment: @RossJacobs - I gave it a try. I'm looking for some suggestions here. Can you pls have a look at the updated question

Comment: @RossJacobs Any help on this is much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Why are you not using mydomain.com as the origin for all requests in the CDN config? There will be a minimal amount of requests from the edge CDN nodes to the origin if you set the cache headers appropriately.

Use your server to fetch the video from IG unless it's not already fetched.

You can set up the origin as a reverse proxy (using Squid for example) and have it manage the cache size if you don't want to save videos in S3. Or set up an S3 policy that clears out files after X number of days.

Comment: 1. `Use your server to fetch the video from IG unless it's not already fetched.` - How to check if the video is already fetched or not?

Comment: 2. `You can set up the origin as a reverse proxy` - Where do I need to do this?

Comment: A sample code snippet would be highly valuable. Much appreciated!